# Encoding troubles with automerge in VS 2012 & TFS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have some problems with encoding when doing automerge with Visual Studio 2012.

I've found a blog post that document the change of the behavior in visual studio : 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2005/09/10/463281.aspx

The blog post states that we need to set the server encoding to be able to solve the problem.

I haven't found a way do this.

Any ideas ?

Comment: It would make sense to ask Buck a question on that blog post, he did update it recently for vs2012.